# Is there a function that can make a OR function in String in IF command

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I want to ask how do you make the computer read 2 string commands as in "sunday" or "tuesday" written below

```
         if (a == "sunday/tuesday")
            Console.WriteLine("take road 1");
        else if (a== "monday/afternon")
            Console.WriteLine("take road 2");
        else 
        Console.WriteLine("take road 3");
```

Thank you

Comment: Something like this `if (day == "sunday" || day == "tuesday")`

Comment: Just as an idea, maybe look into enums. That might be a better way to represent weekdays but I don't know your scenario.

Comment: Hi @chananyaniasoff, welcome to SO. To add to the above, string comparison can be tricky, specially when it comes to cAsE sEnSiTiViTy and padding around the actual string. Keep that in mind.

Comment: thank you it worked but I want to know if there is anyway of making an option "of any afternoon" to be in my case "take road 1"

Comment: You can't do it unless you know exactly what you want. Have you defined all valid inputs? Once you have it'll be easy..

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand what's the valid input.I did define the string that I wanted.thank you

Comment: @chananyaniasoff Your latest edit does not make the question any clearer, worse yet: it makes the comments and answers belong less to the question than before. Not a good edit IMHO, and I advise to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like JSteward answered your original question in the comments, though I'm not sure what you mean by checking "of any afternoon" in your other comments.

If you mean the user could enter `"thursday afternoon"`, and you want to check for the word `"afternoon"` in a string, you can use `day.Contains("afternoon")` which will return true if afternoon appears in the string. Keep in mind it's case sensitive, so something like `day.ToLower().Contains("afternoon")` may be more prudent if the user can enter text themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much